# JasperFillManager.fillReport - Table Component with JSON Data

Tags: json, jasper-reports

I design the jasper (6.20.4) report (in studio IDE) using json data source and the report displays the data in a table....

However when i push the data to run inside the java application server,

`JasperFillManager.fillReport(resourceAsStream, params, ds);`

the above code never returns nor does it throw an exception...

and when I remove that table component, the fillReport returns the print object which later i export to pdf.

Even when use the List (instead of the table), I still never get a JasperPrint

How can I get to know/debug this fillReport ????

Answer (score 0):

I switched to using iText completely by writing the java code (and not relying on jasper fill).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).